# Plotly sunburst plot not showing in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, plotly, plotly-python

I am using Plotly and Jupyter to generate some visuals to better understand user journeys online. I am using the Plotly sunburst chart since this makes a great visual for that purpose. Plotly provides an example that works great and provides the visual that I am looking to produce with my own data. I have created a dataframe that mirrors the example but when I try to use `.show()` no chart is produced. It appears to run fine (no errors) and produces white space where the chart should be but not chart. The data we are testing on ends up being about about 16K rows ultimately.

I have played around with the online vs offline for Plotly neither appeared to make a difference. I tried different labels and ID's. I have also tried restarting the notebook and only running my plot instead of the example first. I have taken my data and narrowed down to only about 50 lines with 4 parent nodes and the rest decedents. All of this got the same result of the white space appearing for the plot but no plot being produced and no errors reported.

```py
import numpy as np                             
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df3=pd.read_csv('sessionsForAnalysis.csv')
df3['parents'] = df3.groupby(['sessionid'])['pagelabel'].shift(1)

df4=df3[['pagelabel','pagelabel','parents']]
df4.columns=["ids", "labels","parents"]
df4=df4.drop_duplicates()

fig1 = go.Figure()

fig1.add_trace(go.Sunburst(
    ids=df4.ids,
    labels=df4.labels,
    parents=df4.parents,
    #values=one_dimensional_array, #I added this
    domain=dict(column=0)
))



fig1.show()
```

I expect this to produce a sunburst plot like below, similar to the one found [here](https://plot.ly/python/sunburst-charts/) except with our data so we can use it to analyze journeys:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a specific solution, but at least a suggestion to the best of my abilities without your particular dataset.

---

My first suspicion was that you did not have the correct packages installed, but since you've stated that

> I have played around with the online vs offline for Plotly neither
>   appeared to make a difference

it seems to me that your problem ***has*** to be your data, specifically the ***type*** or the ***structure*** of your data. From [your referred example](http://I%20have%20played%20around%20with%20the%20online%20vs%20offline%20for%20Plotly%20neither%20appeared%20to%20make%20a%20difference) I tried replacing `values=[10, 14, 12, 10, 2, 6, 6, 4, 4]` with `values=['10', '14', '12', '10', '2', '6', '6', '4', '4']`, but that worked just fine and increases the probability that it's the structure and not type that causes the problems.

Then I messed with the structure, replacing `labels=["Eve", "Cain", "Seth", "Enos", "Noam", "Abel", "Awan", "Enoch", "Azura"]` with 
`labels=["Eve", "Cain", "Noam", "Abel", "Awan", "Enoch", "Azura"]`. Now, no plot is produced with no error messages like this:

[image]

My conclusion: Make sure that each observation in `parents` occurs in `labels`.

Removing `'Noam'` from `labels` is ok. seemingly because `'Noam'` does not occur in `parents`:
[image]

Removing `'Seth'` from labels is not ok:

[image]

So again, make sure that each observation in `parents` occurs in `labels` and see if that works out for you.

Comment: I believe you are correct...... :) I now have to figure out a Pandas dataframe issue to confirm this is the problem but on a small scale I got your solutions to work.

Comment: @Droid Glad to be of assistance! Would you consider marking my suggestion as the accepted amswer? If a better solution comes along, you can always change the 'accepted answer' status.

Comment: open the browser console and you will see the error. Most of the time it is very generic like "unable to build sunburst". But sometimes it may give you a hint like "multiple roots implied".