# plotly express sunburst plot complete blank

Tags: python, plotly, sunburst-diagram

I'm trying to plot a sunburst with plotly express, but the output is a complete blank plot. The code below is from an example showed on the [plotly site](https://plotly.com/python/sunburst-charts/#sunburst-of-a-rectangular-dataframe).
All the examples with `path` give me this output.

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.sunburst(df, path=['day', 'time', 'sex'], values='total_bill')
fig.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Since this code snippet is exactly the same as the code from the Plotly page, it would help potential responders if you include the rest of the code around this to show more of your setup, including how you're managing the data, the packages you've loaded, and more.

Comment: [Plotly sunburst plot not showing in Jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58173316/plotly-sunburst-plot-not-showing-in-jupyter-notebook) I find this answer to be very helpful.

Comment: Do you see any other plotly charts in this notebook or none?

Comment: @SavageHenry In my `.py` file I have only those lines of code. I know that it's the same code from the Plotly page, for this reason it should work.

Comment: @r-beginners Thanks, but this is not my case. If I use the `name` & ´parents´ solutions it works, but I have to edit my df. With the `path` attribute it should be easier tho plot my data.

Comment: @Roy2012 I can see other plotly charts, only the sunburst plots with the `path` attribute give me a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some negative values in your 'total_bill' field?

I found that Sunburst plot returns a blank if the column specified by the 'values' has some negative values. When I drop rows with negative values, the chart renders fine. I don't know if this is a bug though.

I'm running Plotly 5.4.0/Python 3.8.10 in WSL2 on Windows 10.

[Plotly - Jupyter Notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvEYs.png)

Comment: I would recommend asking "Do you have some negative values in your 'total_bill' field?" as a comment under the OP post, not as an answer to OP's post.

Answer (score -2):

You are not providing valid data.
This is what it should be

```
import plotly.express as px
data = dict(
    character=["Eve", "Cain", "Seth", "Enos", "Noam", "Abel", "Awan", "Enoch", "Azura"],
    parent=["", "Eve", "Eve", "Seth", "Seth", "Eve", "Eve", "Awan", "Eve" ],
    value=[10, 14, 12, 10, 2, 6, 6, 4, 4])

fig = px.sunburst(
    data,
    names='character',
    parents='parent',
    values='value',
)

fig.show()
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Did you try the code he provided? It does actually provide a sunburst diagram.